# Py2Exe - "The application configuration is incorrect."

Tags: python, wxpython, compilation, py2exe

I've compiled my Python program using Py2Exe, and on the client's computer we've satisfied all the dependencies using dependency walker, but we still get "The application configuration is incorrect.  Reinstalling the application may correct the problem."  I'm also using wxPython.

The client does not have administrator access.

Any ideas?

Comment: This error sounds familiar... you're missing a DLL. I've no idea which one though, sorry.

Comment: Good that you found a workaround (downgrading python). I had the same error once (assume you are using Windows) and i think i just had to play around with the XML-manifest file which was added by py2exe. You might want to post your setup.py and manifest file and i'll have a look at it.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question here:<br/>
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323424> At that link is a more complete discussion of what is wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran into this myself and my random Googling has pointed me to several people saying to downgrade python 2.6 to 2.5, which worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Give [GUI2exe](http://code.google.com/p/gui2exe/) a shot; it's developed by Andrea Gavana who's big in the wxpython community and wraps a bunch of the freezers, including py2exe.  It's likely a dll issue, try [searching the wxpython list archive](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=90t&q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Flists.wxwidgets.org%2Fpipermail%2Fwxpython-users%2F+%2B%22py2exe%22+%2Bdll&btnG=Search).  [This thread](http://lists.wxwidgets.org/pipermail/wxpython-users/2008-November/081956.html) may be of use.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this same issue with python 2.6, PyQt and py2exe. The root cause was a missing dependency, resolved by installing [the visual studio 2008 SP1 redist(x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar problem few minutes ago. I couldn't run py2exe installation file, it kept saying that application configuration was incorrect. Downgrading to python 2.5 didn't work for me because I used 'with' statements through out the code and didn't want to change it.

I reinstalled python 2.6 and I checked the option that says that anyone on the computer can use python. Worked out just fine.