# Making a Windows .exe with gui2exe does not work because of missing MSVCP90.dll

Tags: python, dll, wxwidgets, py2exe, gui2exe

I'm trying to compile my python script into a single .exe using gui2exe (which uses py2exe to create a .exe). My program is using wxWidgets and everytime I try to compile it I get the following error message:

> error MSVCP90.dll: No such file or directory.

I have already downloaded and installed the VC++ redistributable package, so I should have this .dll shouldn't I?

Comment: BTW: AFAIK, This is a known problem with Python 2.6 and py2exe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you should have it. You have to exclude it from py2exe.

```
options = {
    'py2exe': {
        'dll_excludes': [
            'MSVCP90.dll'
         ]
     }
}

setup(windows=["main.py"], options=options)
```

Comment: Um? What? Can you be a little more specific.

Comment: Sure, I hope this example helps,

Comment: Ok, You spelled options wrong. I fixed it and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. :) You should be aware, that you have to install MSVCP90.DLL on the target PC yourself now. For more information look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323424/py2exe-fails-to-generate-an-executable

Comment: works great!
with
python-2.7.2.msi  + 
wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.12.1-py27.exe + 
py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.7.exe

Answer (score 1):

what you need is to go to microsoft's download site and get visual C++ 2008 redistributed package.  Tell it to do a repair and search for the driver.  Copy the driver to the DLL folder in the python directory