# py2exe can't find msvcp90.dll

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe

I'm working on converting a simple GUI script written with Python 2.7 and Pyqt4 into a standalone executable using py2exe. I keep getting "no such file exists" errors, and I've managed to fix a few, though this one seems stubborn. It can't find msvcp90.dll, and returns an error message with a short traceback to distutils and then back to my py2exe script, which isn't very enlightening.
I've installed the MS C++ redistributable runtime, as recommended in

[py2exe fails to generate an executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323424/py2exe-fails-to-generate-an-executable)

but my script still can't locate the .dll. Below is my py2exe script, with the name of my script blocked out:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from py2exe.build_exe import py2exe
import sys, os, zmq

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

os.environ["PATH"] = \
os.environ["PATH"] + \
os.path.pathsep + os.path.split(zmq.__file__)[0]

setup(
    options = {'py2exe':{'bundle_files':1,"includes":["zmq.utils", 
            "zmq.utils.jsonapi","zmq.utils.strtypes"]}},
    console = [{'script':"#######.py"}],
    zipfile = None
)
```

I've already fixed an issue with zmq (which isn't ever used by my script, or my GUI, for that matter, as far as I know). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the reason zmq is included is due to the ```"includes":["zmq.``` stuff (and possibly the ```import sys, os, zmq``` stanza too).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right, I've managed to get my app to build, and although the question is now moderately old, it's my hope this is eventually of use to someone.

**Firstly,** py2exe is probably the wrong tool. It's old and AFAICT unmaintained. Consider PyInstaller instead. Using PyInstaller is literally as simple as installing it, installing PyWin32, and then going `python %path_to_pyinstaller%/pyinstaller.py --onefile --windowed source.py`. PyInstaller deals with all the mess of side by side assemblies and so on without you having to do anything.

*In short, use PyInstaller.*

**However,** to answer your question, this worked for me:

1. The question you've linked to - in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325456/463510) is the right start. Find the right DLLs and copy them to C:\Python27\DLLs
2. Ditch your existing `setup.py` file. If you're not using `zmq`, there's no reason to import it. Also, for a windowed application you want `windows=` not `console=`. My file goes (for packaging `show.py`):

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python

   from distutils.core import setup
   import py2exe

   setup(options={'py2exe':{'bundle_files':1}},
         windows=['show.py'])
   ```

   (This is pinched off http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/31/a-py2exe-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/)

Comment: Your solution got my script to build an exe, but it's still not quite functioning right. Still, my issue's solved. Thanks.

Comment: Turns out that Thomas Heller is still contributing! http://sourceforge.net/p/py2exe/svn/737/tree/trunk/py2exe/ChangeLog

Comment: It's quite true that [`pyinstaller`](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/commits/develop) is more active than [`py2exe`](http://sourceforge.net/p/py2exe/svn/737/tree/trunk/py2exe/ChangeLog).