# wxPython/Py2exe: Trouble running exe file

Tags: wxpython, py2exe

Good day all,

I developed a desktop app using wxPython GUI and created an .exe file for it using Py2exe. But when I run/launch the .exe file it says “is not a valid win32 application”.

What could have gone wrong with my process?

[image]

**History:**

1)  My installation is: Windows 32-bit, Python 2.7.6, wxPython3

2)  I have successfully done this process using my old PC

3)  Now that am using a new PC with the same installation, it first complained of missing msvcp90.dll file and I downloaded one [here](http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?msvcp90) (the Manual fix) to fix that.

4)  After creating the exe file (with the new PC), it won’t run/launch

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: was your app created on your old pc? was the old pc 64-bit?

Comment: It could be some version mismatch of msvcp90. try searching it in your windows directly and manually copy one of those to your build folder.

Comment: @NGambit YES, it was created on my old PC it was 32-bit. (I lost the old PC, no way to lay my hands on it, am regretting)

Comment: @otterb, kindly clarify how I would go about searching it (the missing msvcp90.dll file) in my windows directly?

Comment: I just use explorer's search window. If you don't see any, try installing Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/a/325456/566035

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the `.exe` in the same computer? I encountered this problem once when trying to run a program created in 64 bit Windows and python on a 32 bit PC.

If you need to run it on a 32 bit PC try creating the executable in the same

Comment: I created it on the same computer.